# What is this floating point format?

Tags: binary, floating-point, binaryfiles

I am trying to figure out how to read a historical binary data file.  I believe it came from an older 32 bit Solaris system.  I am looking at a section of the file that I believe contains 32 bit floating numbers (not IEEE floats).  The format appears to be (as a hex dump):

```
xx41 xxxx
xx42 xxxx
```

The 41 and 42 in those positions appear consistently through the floating point numbers.  I'm afraid that I do not have any additional information to add to this.  So the first part of my question is, what format is this? If the first part can not be answered directly, a list of likely possibilities would be great.  Lastly, how would you suggest going about determining what format this is?  Thank you for your input.

Comment: Do you have a few numbers these map to (e.g. 1141 1111 maps to 3.5)?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I'll know when I have the right format, because there should be some consistency or pattern to the numbers once they are in the right format.  I do not have any direct mapping between the binary and a known float at this time.  Though that is a good idea.

Comment: Roughly how many values do you have?  There's not a lot of information here to work with :-).  I realise the data are probably private, but what would be *really* interesting to see (and probably wouldn't give valuable data away) is a table or histogram showing how often each *first* byte value (0-255) is taken.  (A similar table for the 2nd byte might be interesting too;  I'd expect the 3rd and 4th to be less interesting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data described is consistent with the usual IEEE 754 format, stored in big-endian order, then displayed by a little-endian dump program two bytes at a time.

32-bit floats in the interval [8, 128) have first bytes of 0x41 or 0x42. Consider such a number, perhaps 0x41010203. Stored big end first, it would appear in memory as the four bytes 0x41, 0x01, 0x02, and 0x03. When the dump program reads 16-byte integers, little end first, it will read and display 0x0141 and 0x0302.

Comment: Hmm, true.  I can't think of a useful test that would distinguish between the IEEE 754 binary32 and the PDP-11 / VAX F formats: both have 8-bit exponents and 24-bit fractions;  both make use of the hidden bit.  IEEE specials don't help, since they probably don't feature in the data set.  The most obvious difference is in the bias, and that's not going to help unless the OP has some outside information about the scale of his data.

Comment: Thank you Eric!  This exactly the answer.  Good call.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be PDP-11 format?   The giveaway for me is that the *second* byte is mostly constant, which suggests that the exponent of the floating-point format is ending up in the second byte rather than the first (as you'd expect for a big-endian machine) or the last (for a little-endian machine).  The PDP-11 is notorious for its funny byte order for floats and integers;  see the material near the bottom of this [Floating-Point Formats](http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/cp0201.htm) page.

The values of `41` and `42` would appear to be consistent with positive values of roughly unit-magnitude:  the exponent bias for the PDP-11 format appears to be `128`, so with the unusual byte-order I'd expect the 2nd byte that you list to contain the sign and the topmost 7 bits of the exponent;  that would make the unbiased exponent for a second byte of `41` be either 2 or 3 depending on the 8th exponent bit (which should appear as the MSB of the first byte).

See also [this page](http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nssdc/formats/PDP-11.htm) for a brief description of the PDP-11 format.

[EDIT] Here's some Python code to convert from a 4-byte string in the form you describe to a Python float, assuming that the 4-byte string represents a float in PDP-11 format.

```
import struct

def pdp_to_float(xs):
    """Convert a 4-byte PDP-11 single-precision float to a Python float."""

    ordered_bytes = ''.join(xs[i] for i in [1, 0, 3, 2])
    n = struct.unpack('>I', ordered_bytes)[0]

    fraction = n & 0x007fffff
    exponent = (n & 0x7f800000) >> 23
    sign = (n & 0x80000000) >> 31

    hidden = 1 if exponent != 0 else 0
    return (-1)**sign * 2**(exponent-128) * (hidden + fraction / 2.0**23)
```

Example:

```
>>> pdp_to_float('\x00\x00\x00\x00')
0.0
>>> pdp_to_float('\x23\x41\x01\x00')
5.093750476837158
>>> pdp_to_float('\x00\x42\x00\x00')
16.0
```

Comment: Great response!  I have not been able to test it yet, but one small additional bit of information that might be useful is that I suspect all of the floating point values will be positive.  Does that change your inclination any?

Comment: No, that would be consistent with the data you've given:  *if* the hypothesis is correct, then the sign bit is the topmost bit of the second byte.  So 2nd byte values in the range `0x00` to `0x7f` would correspond to positive numbers, and 2nd byte values in the range `0x80` through `0xff` would correspond to negative numbers.